# Teamcity Kotlin Build Base Class Property Extension

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, kotlin-dsl

I've extracted my Teamcity builds as Kotlin outputs. I want to create a base class that defines a number of common steps/settings, but allow individual builds to extend these properties.

e.g.

```
open class BuildBase(init: BuildBase.() -> Unit) : BuildType({
    steps {
        powerShell {
            name = "Write First Message"
            id = "RUNNER_FirstMessage"
            scriptMode = script {
                content = """
                    Write-Host "First Message"
                """.trimIndent()
            }
        }
    }
})

object Mybuild : BuildBase({
    steps { // This would add a new step to the list, without wiping out the original step
        powerShell {
            name = "Write Last Message"
            id = "RUNNER_LastMessage"
            scriptMode = script {
                content = """
                    Write-Host "Last Message"
                """.trimIndent()
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In this example, I want to inherit the step from the base class, but add additional steps relevant to the specific build. Additionally, I'd want to inherit the base `disableSettings` (if any) and disable other steps.

Is this even possible? if so, how would I go about structuring the classes to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have found a solution already but here's how I would solve your problem.

Like in the GUI, TeamCity supports build templates.
In your case you would have a template like following:

```
object MyBuildTemplate: Template({
  id("MyBuildTemplate")
  name = "My build template"

  steps {
    powerShell {
        name = "Write First Message"
        id = "RUNNER_FirstMessage"
        scriptMode = script {
            content = """
                Write-Host "First Message"
            """.trimIndent()
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Then, you can define a build config extending this template:

```
object MyBuildConfig: BuildType({
  id("MyBuildConfig")
  name = "My build config"

  steps { // This would add a new step to the list, without wiping out the original step
    powerShell {
        name = "Write Last Message"
        id = "RUNNER_LastMessage"
        scriptMode = script {
            content = """
                Write-Host "Last Message"
            """.trimIndent()
        }
    }

    // afaik TeamCity would append the build config's steps to the template's steps but there is way to explicitly define the order of the steps:
    stepsOrder = arrayListOf("RUNNER_FirstMessage", "RUNNER_LastMessage")
  }
})
```

This way, you should also be able to inherit `disableSettings` from the template.